# appending strings together in VS2010 c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, if-statement, for-loop, c++-cli

I have written a code that have a `if` condition. After checking `if` then I want to show the results in a TexBox. The `if` statement is satisfied for more than one case and then I need to append them.

For example:

```
for (i=1;i<10;i++){
    if (i > 8){
       String^ Num = Convert::ToString(i);
       textbox1->Text = Num;
    }
}
```

The answer is `10`. But I want to have `8,9,10`.
How Could I have such a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String^ Num = "";
for (i=1;i<10;i++){
    if (i > 8){
       Num = Convert::ToString(i);
       if(Num == "")//first iteration so don't add ", "
       {
           textbox1-> += Num;
       }
       else
       {
           textbox1->Text += ", " + Num;
    }
}
```

The default behavior of the string::operator+ is to concatenate so += will just concatenate whatever is already in the string with what the new value is. So assuming the Text field is a string this should work.  Apologies for the lack of explanation.

Comment: Answers that are accompanied with a description of *why* this is the solution are much more effective.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case I put `Num = Convert::ToString(i);` inside `else`